# Azure ServiceBus as proxy between protexted resource and public client

Tags: proxy, azureservicebus

I have a REST WebApi which is hosted in an intranet so it is not available outside the company network. I have an Azure Function which needs to make a request to that WebApi.

The WebApi is not available to the outer world so Azure Function cant use it, but it can connect to Azure ServiceBus, I was thinking use Queue as a proxy for a WepApi calls/request. So, the Azure Function would create a message with CorrelationId, send it to the Queue and wait for a response in other Queue(pairing with the stored CorrelationId).

Does that makes sense? Aren't there any solutions for that already? I was googling for "servicebus proxy" etc. but with no success.

Comment: Have you looked at ASB / Azure Relays?

Comment: @SlavaAsipenko You mean this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-relay/relay-what-is-it ?

Comment: Yes, that one. Not 100% sure it will work for you, but feels  along the lines of what you were looking for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I was looking for
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-relay/relay-what-is-it

Works like a charm.

@SlavaAsipenko: Thank you.